# In rails, tinymce's toolbar isn't showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, toolbar

I have installed the tinymce gem. My tinymce can process the html tags but the toolbar isn't coming. Here is my view file's code:

```
    <%= tinymce_assets %>
    <div class="container">
    <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <table summary="Product for fields"  class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:title) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <!--td><%= f.text_field(:description) %></td-->
        <td><%= f.text_area :description, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 2, :cols => 120 %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:price) %></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= f.submit "Create Products", :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', products_path,  :class => 'btn btn-info' %>
    </div>
    <%= tinymce %>
```

Here is my configuration file ( I mean tinymce.yml):

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
menubar: false
toolbar:
  [ styleselect | bold italic | link image | code ]

plugins:
  - link
  - image
```

and here is the application.js file

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {

  if (typeof tinyMCE != 'undefined') {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    tinyMCE.init({
      selector: "textarea.tinymce",
      toolbar: [
        "styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
        "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code | codesample"
      ],
      plugins: "image,link,code,codesample,autoresize,imagetools,media,table,insertdatetime,charmap,print,preview,anchor,searchreplace,visualblocks,fullscreen"
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50);
  }
});
```

And while I am running this code the browser console is showing the following  error : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TinyMCERails. And I cannot find out the solution.

Comment: followed ReadMe https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails to integrate?

Comment: yeah. followed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was if we use that configuration file, we cannot use the application.js file too. So, just deleting that application.js file solved the problem for me.